# Using a unique_ptr as a class member variable

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

I have a class `Page` which needs a `Background` object (in my project each page has a background). The `Background` is the base class of other classes (e.g. `RuledBackground` or `DottedBackground`) that specify the background in more detail. Because of this, I need polymorphism so I have to store the `Background` object using a pointer. However, since each `Page` essentially "owns" a unique `Background` object I thought I would use a `std::unique_ptr<Background>` in my `Page` class, so the background of each page is automatically deleted when the page is destroyed. The code below illustrates my class structure:

```
class Page{
public:
    Background* background() {
        return m_background.get();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Background> m_background;
};
```

In the code above instead of returning the `unique_ptr`, I am directly returning the raw pointer for the background, because it is my understanding that passing around a raw pointer is fine (or is it not?). The problem I see with my approach is to figure out how to initialize the raw pointer from outside the class, something like this

```
    void setBackground(Background *bg){
        m_background = std::make_unique<Background>(bg);
    }
```

seems quite bad (since I suppose I will need to create the raw pointer somewhere).
The other approach I thought about is to be make the `unique_ptr` a public member variable and return a reference to it and then I can initialise it from outside the class.
What would be the most elegant and safest solution to what I just described? Is there a better alternative that does the same thing?

Comment: if you need to share the pointer, maybe `unique_ptr` might sound a bit wrong, and maybe `shared_ptr` might sounds better

Comment: @Berto99 in my project each page essentially has one background, so I think when the page is destroyed the background should be too.

Comment: `void setBackground(std::unique_ptr<Background> bg) { m_background = std::move(bg); }` since the caller is handing off ownership to the Page object.

Comment: if you are sure that there is no case where someone can maintain any reference to that object, you can use `std::move` to move the pointer to the unique_ptr

Comment: @Berto99 `std::move` on a `std::unique_ptr<T>` does not invalidate references to the pointed object. The pointed object is not moved. It it always safe to `std::move` a `std::unique_ptr` that was passed by value to a function. It can't invalidate anything and you already have unique ownership of the object.

Comment: If your object is supposed to assume ownership of the background, then `m_background = bg;` is fine. However I recommend `setBackground(std::unique_ptr<Background> bg)` since it conveys the intent of transferring ownership.

Comment: Regarding your pointer question, since you don't want to transfer ownership it's fine to return an pointer.But you can also return an reference to the background if you are 100% sure that the pointer will never be null. `Background& background() {return *m_background}`. Although we dereference the pointer it won't create an copy.